# Javascript getElementsByName() for changing names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a automatically rendered HTML form which uses a index for the input fields.

for quantity:

```
<input id="id_orderline_set-0-orderline_quantity" name="orderline_set-0-orderline_quantity" onkeyup="orderlineTotal()" type="number" value="120">
```

for product price;

```
<input id="id_orderline_set-0-orderline_product_price" name="orderline_set-0-orderline_product_price" onkeyup="orderlineTotal()" type="number" value="22">
```

for total line price;

```
<input id="id_orderline_set-0-orderline_total_price" name="orderline_set-0-orderline_total_price" tag="orderline_total_price" type="number" value="2640">
```

For the following lines the index of the id and name are increased, only quantity example shown;

```
<input id="id_orderline_set-1-orderline_quantity" name="orderline_set-1-orderline_quantity" onkeyup="orderlineTotal()"  type="number" value="55">
```

I would like to use the following JavaScript to calculate the total line price;

```
function orderlineTotal()
{
    var orderlineTotalPrice = 0;   
    var theForm = document.forms["orderform"];

    var orderlineQuantityField = theForm.getElementsByName["orderline_quantity"];
    var orderlineProductPriceField = theForm.getElementsByName["orderline_product_price"];
    var orderlineTotalPriceField = theForm.getElementsByName["orderline_total_price"];

    for (var i = 0; i < orderlineQuantityField.length; i ++) {
        orderlineTotalPrice = orderlineQuantityField[i].value * orderlineProductPriceField[i].value;
        orderlineTotalPriceField[i].value = orderlineTotalPrice;
    }
}
```

Offcourse this wont work because the name of the elements do not match. Can i lookup the name of the element by using a partial name? If not, how should i loop through the input boxes to calculate the line total?

Comment: Add a common class name to the elements you want to sum and then use `getElementsByClassName()`.  You can have as many different class names on any given object so you can always add a class name to a set of objects for purposes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged jQuery so if you want to use jQuery you can use ends with selector:

```
$("input[name$='orderline_quantity']")
```

[ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

there's also

[starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("input[name^='id_orderline_set-0']")
```

and [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("input[name*='orderline_']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use static names. Set the equal input names for inputs of the same type and then use this function:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('name');
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    doSomething(elements[i]);
}
```

where name matches name of input.

## Example

Instead of:

```
name="orderline_set-0-orderline_total_price"
```

use:

```
name="orderline_total_price"
```

and then:

```
var orderlineTotalPriceField = theForm.getElementsByName["orderline_total_price"];
```

and so on...